# How to show a Bayes Update is Normal Economics Example

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with an example of Bayesian updating in economics. The problem I'm trying to solve is from Sargent and Ljungvist's Recursive Macroeconomic Theory, Chapter 6.

A firm wishes to offer a wage to a potential employee that's equal to his/her expected productivity. However, the firm only observes a noisy signal of the productivity.

Productivity is given by $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma_0^2)$. Noisy signal observed is $y=\theta+u$ where $u \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_u^2)$. I'm looking to find $E(\theta \mid y=\theta+u)$ and $Var(\theta \mid y=\theta+u)$. The random variables $\theta$, $u$ are independent.

This is solvable by bayesian updating and indeed the textbook gives the solutions:

\begin{equation} E(\theta \mid y=\theta+u)=\frac{\sigma^2_0}{\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_u}y+\frac{\sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_u}\mu \end{equation} \begin{equation} Var(\theta \mid y=\theta+u)=\frac{\sigma^2_0 \sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_u} \end{equation}

The authors derive the solution using the Kalman Filter but I was hoping to do it by using Bayes rule explicitly, i.e. multiplying the densities together, completing the square and showing the mean and variance are as given above. That is:

\begin{equation} p(\theta \mid y=\theta+u) \propto p(y=\theta+u \mid \theta) \cdot p(\theta) \end{equation}

Unfortunately I just cant get it to work. I was hoping that someone could maybe give me a pointer. Many thanks.